# In the US, I open doors, but in the UK, I am used for profit. What am I?

Tags: riddle

This is a simple one liner that someone told me at a group meetup. I think it's deceptively simple - we'll see how long it lasts :)

**In the US, I open doors, but in the UK, I am used for profit. What am I?**

Hint:

> No matter where you are, it performs the same function.

Hint:

> This is a common object - the riddle does not describe its function, but rather, its name

Hint:

> You almost certainly own one of these

Super mega spoiler hint:

> It's right under you nose

Comment: Any hints? This is a little bit too trickerish...

Comment: @Snickbrack You are correct - I should have added them earlier. No answers correct so far :)

Comment: More bloody hints eh chap. At least if it's not answered so far

Comment: @JasonCemra Since this question is closed now, can you add the answer?

Comment: @AvikMohan You're right - sorry I took so long :) These last two hints ought to narrow it down.

Comment: Even after reading your "super mega spoiler" hint I don't have an answer. Perhaps my English idioms aren't up to par? In any case... perhaps a ROT13 encoded answer?

Comment: I altered my answer based on the hints.

Comment: @JasonCemra Hints don't count towards the question being too broad.

Comment: Maybe the riddle wasn't very good... The answer is "Enter / Return key". In the US (and other places) a door must be opened before one can enter, and in the UK (and other places) , return is synonymous with profit. As for the hints, they should be self explanatory. The location in the riddle was for the *name* in that location and nothing else. Anyway, hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 16):

Is it:

> A pound?

Because:

> In US: It can mean knocking on a door
>  In UK: It's the name of the currency

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Good answer and right where my mind went, (+1) but the reasoning for US works just as well in the UK.  I'm unsure about this too but maybe it's something to do with the symbols.  In name, US#=UK£ and the # key could be used to open some doors via keypad.

Comment: I think this could be right, Jason Cemra did say it was deceptively simple and nothing says that either explanation has to be exclusive.  That does fit for a more common use for each respective country.

Comment: How does this fit the last hint?

Comment: My post was way before any of those hints were there - sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

> Quid

As in the UK:

> "Quid" is terminology  for £1

And in America:

> Quid Pro Quo is defined as - *a favour or advantage granted in return for something.*

Which is synonymous with:

> Opening Doors

Comment: Again, what works for the US works for the UK.

Comment: Ah, the only place I'd ever heard the term was in American TV shows so assumed incorrectly. Oh well :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> Wedge

In the UK (slang):

> Wedge can be used for a quantity of money (I live in London and would say this is uncommon though)

In the US (and indeed everywhere...):

> A wedge holds a door open

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Security?

In the US:

> A security officer can open the door for you

In the UK:

> Securities is another name for proof of stocks/ bonds.

Comment: Good answer! But, no, sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the "for profit" bit is chiefly British, but I think the answer is

> handle

because you open doors with

> a handle

and

> to buy or sell something is to handle it. Buying and selling is done for profit. But I couldn't see anything in the dictionary to indicate this is chiefly British usage, so I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> slim jim

In the U.S.

> Opens car doors

In the U.K.

> They're pants which are bought and sold of course.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't tell me its just

> a knob

Note that in the uk

> prostitution is legal, so this may be the profit side of it

Comment: No - the answer isn't _that_ simple :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be:

> [Gearing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gearing)
>
>  In UK it means: The ratio of a company’s loan capital (debt) to the value of its ordinary shares (equity)
>
>  In US: The set or arrangement of gears in a machine, which may open doors in some mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> A Mouth?

In the UK

> Call out to advertise your wares you are selling

In the US

> Call out to ask if anyone is home

:-/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> Stock

Although this can be used for profit in both countries, I have found some dictionaries citing it as a synonym for

> Handle. Eg the Oxford "8.2 The **handle** of something such as a whip or fishing rod. Perhaps in the US the link to handle is stronger